# Google Maps API V2 key suddenly stopped working

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on a team where we are developing an app which is fully dependent on a Google Maps fragment.

Suddenly it stopped working for me, all I see is a grey square with the normal Google Maps tools overlaying. It works fine for everyone else on the team.

```
10-28 09:52:51.909 32060-32338/com.astudio.andreas.mapstest E/b: Authentication failed on the server.
10-28 09:52:51.910 32060-32338/com.astudio.andreas.mapstest E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
10-28 09:52:51.914 32060-32338/com.astudio.andreas.mapstest E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
10-28 09:52:51.914 32060-32338/com.astudio.andreas.mapstest E/Google Maps Android API: Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
10-28 09:52:51.914 32060-32338/com.astudio.andreas.mapstest E/Google Maps Android API: Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
10-28 09:52:51.914 32060-32338/com.astudio.andreas.mapstest E/Google Maps Android API:  API Key: 
10-28 09:52:51.914 32060-32338/com.astudio.andreas.mapstest E/Google Maps Android API:  Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 50:DA:86:04:6A:(etcetra etcetra)
```

This happens in Logcat. It was fine until I reset cache for the app in my Android Phone, now everything is grey.

I have reset my local repository to the latest commit on BitBucket, but still I get an error.

[image]

Comment: change the `API key`. Generate a new Key with your `SHA-1`

Comment: @MD Tried that, samme error in Logcat and no map visible.

Comment: did you change the main package of your app?

Answer (score 1):

Did you running your project on same development machine, because if you run  project on different development machine, then you have to create new api key again on google console, with the SHA fingerprint of your new machine.

Comment: Tried that. Made a new project in Google Developer Console, generated key with my SHA-1 fingerprint. Still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Activate the Google Maps Android API v2 service in the Google API's console. Also, after making changes do a full reinstall of the app on the device/emulator.

Comment: yes exactly this one and also if u are using old API key then create a new one and add it to your menifest file and reinstall app.

Answer (score 0):

I set the key from Google Developer Console in a file called google_maps_api.xml in res/values but found that it also had to be set in AndroidManifest.xml. Now it works perfectly again.